# php file_get_contents command does not work

Tags: php, nginx, freebsd

I started doing research to extract data from websites and found some documents and run them on my local host, then I uploaded the code to my server, but the data did not come

freebsd12.2 Stable

pkgs:
nginx-1.20.0_1,2
php80-8.0.6

my website code:

```
  <?php

function getir($baslangic, $son, $cekilmek_istenen)
{
    @preg_match_all('/' . preg_quote($baslangic, '/') .
    '(.*?)'. preg_quote($son, '/').'/i', $cekilmek_istenen, $m);
    return @$m[1];
}



//Ankr Coin
$url = "https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/ankr/";

$icerik = file_get_contents($url);

$AnkrCoin = getir('<div class="priceValue___11gHJ">','</div>',$icerik);




//Eose
$url = "https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/eos/";

$icerik = file_get_contents($url);

$EosCoin = getir('<div class="priceValue___11gHJ">','</div>',$icerik);



//Atom
$url = "https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/cosmos/";

$icerik = file_get_contents($url);

$CosmosAtom = getir('<div class="priceValue___11gHJ">','</div>',$icerik);




//Mkr
$url = "https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/maker/";

$icerik = file_get_contents($url);

$Mkr = getir('<div class="priceValue___11gHJ">','</div>',$icerik);
?>

<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5">
</head>

<body>

  <div id="AnkCoin">
    <p>
      Ankr:<?php echo $AnkrCoin[0]; ?>
    </p>
  </div>

  <div>
    <p>
      Eos: <?php echo $EosCoin[0]; ?>
    </p>
  </div>

  <div>
    <p>
      Cosmos Atom: <?php echo $CosmosAtom[0]; ?>
    </p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>
      Mkr: <?php echo $Mkr[0]; ?>
    </p>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I can see google in the expressions like this command

```
<?php
$homepage = file_get_contents('http://www.google.com/');
echo $homepage;
?>
```

but nothing happens when i change the link
for example

```
<?php
$homepage = file_get_contents('https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/eos/');
echo $homepage;
?>
```

My error logs are clean.

Comment: Instead of `file_get_contents()` use `curl` because `file_get_contents()` doesn't follow redirection/Refresh. But if you still need to use `file_get_contents()`, check this https://www.php.net/manual/en/context.http.php

Comment: @Haridarshan I try curl too 
but nothing has changed

Comment: I've just tried for this url `https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/eos/` via `curl` and i got response. So, can you please share the curl code which you've tried

Answer (score 0):

I've tried myself and it's working, getting output

```php
<?php
function call($url)
{ 
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    $httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    curl_close($ch);
    
    if ($httpcode !== 200) {
        return null;
    }

    return $output;
}

function getir($baslangic, $son, $cekilmek_istenen)
{
    @preg_match_all('/' . preg_quote($baslangic, '/') .
    '(.*?)'. preg_quote($son, '/').'/i', $cekilmek_istenen, $m);
    return @$m[1];
}


//Ankr Coin
$url = "https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/ankr/";
$icerik = call($url);
$AnkrCoin = getir('<div class="priceValue___11gHJ">','</div>',$icerik);

//Eose
$url = "https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/eos/";
$icerik = call($url);
$EosCoin = getir('<div class="priceValue___11gHJ">','</div>',$icerik);



//Atom
$url = "https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/cosmos/";
$icerik = call($url);
$CosmosAtom = getir('<div class="priceValue___11gHJ">','</div>',$icerik);

//Mkr
$url = "https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/maker/";
$icerik = call($url);
$Mkr = getir('<div class="priceValue___11gHJ">','</div>',$icerik);
?>

<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5">
</head>

<body>

  <div id="AnkCoin">
    <p>
      Ankr:<?php echo $AnkrCoin[0]; ?>
    </p>
  </div>

  <div>
    <p>
      Eos: <?php echo $EosCoin[0]; ?>
    </p>
  </div>

  <div>
    <p>
      Cosmos Atom: <?php echo $CosmosAtom[0]; ?>
    </p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>
      Mkr: <?php echo $Mkr[0]; ?>
    </p>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: your code is running but I don't understand why my code is not working on the server while running local

Comment: @hiqermod Can you please share the output of `$info` from server

Comment: did u mean phpinfo(); ? sorry ım beginner

Comment: @hiqermod no, if you run my code on your server what is the output of this `echo json_encode($info);`

Comment: I want to clip the data I want from another website I want to do, as in the above code, now I am alienated from the subject because the structure of the code has changed. Isn't there a way to use my own code or how do I do this in curl?

Comment: @hiqermod I've modified the answer